# phpMyAdmin foreign key for DateTime value not working as intended

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I've searched but can't find anyone else having the exact same issue.

I have set up an InnoDB in phpMyAdmin.

Simple DB for meetings.

Table 1: Room

attributes; RoomID (int and primary key), Room (varchar for room name)

Table 2: TimeSlot

attributes; TimeSlotID (int and primary key), TimeSlot (DateTime)

Table 3: Meeting

attributes; MeetingID (int and primary key), Room (int), TimeSlot (int)

I have used foreign key constraints in the relation view to link Room primary key and TimeSlot primary key to the Meeting table.

Foreign Key 1

Restrict the Room attribute in Meeting table to the Room table & its primary key RoomID.

Foreign Key 2

Restrict the TimeSlot attribute in Meeting table to the TimeSlot table & its primary key TimeSlotID.

It works for booking Rooms. When inserting a new meeting a drop down for the Room attribute gives both the RoomID (int and primary key) and the Room (varchar name).

However for the TimeSlot selection when booking a meeting the drop down only shows the TimeSlot primary key, not the DateTime associated with it which makes it difficult to know what time the random ID relates to.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here. The only difference is that one is a varchar and one is DateTime - if thats the problem - is there a way to bring through the related DateTime information?

Screen prints:

[room data types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOv41.png)

[timeslot data types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTeze.png)

[meeting data types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6xZB.png)

[relation view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6nAC.png)

[room selection working as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PmNd.png)

[timeslot selection not working as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izxzI.png)

Comment: That's a lot of links that would be better as data in the question.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. I've now provided more detail on the foreign keys within the question. The links are screen prints just covering what i've described, no additional info, just maybe useful in case my description doesn't make sense - don't have rights yet to embed pics.